# How to take quality framegrabs of 1080i video?

Tags: video, high-definition

Our group has a set of high definition footage taken in 1080i (.mov) that we want to analyse by taking framegrabs.

However, since this is interlaced footage, I was told that if I grab one frame, I only get an image that's half the video's resolution. Is there a way for me to "de-interlace" the framegrab to boost its quality?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Theoretically any decent video player comes with deinterlacing and should handle screengrabs fine.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can Apple's Quicktime 7 or X do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [VLC](http://videolan.org), you should be able to take some very nice frameshots if you [deinterlace](http://wiki.videolan.org/Deinterlacing#VLC_deinterlace_modes) (`Tools -> Prefererences -> Video -> Video -> Deinterlacing`) the video and hit `Video -> Snapshot` (or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

On a Mac, the combo would be <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

MPlayer can do this

> MPlayer comes with a very nice and
>   easy to use video filter that allows
>   taking single or multiple screenshots.
>   The syntax is simple:
>
> Code:
>
> mplayer -vf screenshot my_file.mp4
>
> Simply pressing the 's' key takes a
>   single screenshot in png format in the
>   working directory. If you wish to take
>   a series of screenshots you can press
>   the 'S' key and MPlayer will keep
>   taking screenshots until the 'S' key
>   is pressed again. However if this is a
>   little too straightforward for you
>   MPlayer also can also output images in
>   a slightly different way that has a
>   few more options:
>
> Code:
>
> mplayer -nosound -frames 5 -vo png:z=9
>   my_file.mp4
>
> This will output the first 5 frames of
>   the media file in high quality png
>   format into the working directory.
>   Similar screenshots can be taken by
>   using jpeg, gif89a, targa and pnm as
>   '-vo'. How incredibly cool is that!